# How can i get the index of the child node clicked

Tags: javascript

I have 3 span items in a div container, 
when a user clicks on any of the item 
in the container, since the div(container) is the parentNode of the (item) span elements. i want to get the index of the (item)span element clicked.

"how can i get the index of the child node clicked"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have something like this:

```
document.querySelector("div").onclick = ({target}) => {
  let index = 0;
  while (target = target.previousElementSibling) {
    index++;
  }

  console.log(index);
}
```

The logic is the following: you add an event listener to the container (the div, assuming you have only the span as children, otherwise you need either to filter the `target` to react only to span, or add the listener to each span), and then from the `span` clicked, you get the previous sibling element, until there isn't any – so you reach the first child element of the container – and you return the iteration count.

Another approach could be:

```
const getIndex = (target, list) =>
  Array.prototype.indexOf.call(list, target)

const div = document.querySelector("div");
const span = div.querySelectorAll("span");

console.log(getIndex(span[1], span)) // 1
```

This is more generic: it gives you the position of an object inside an array-like object, so it works for NodeList but not only. Plus, you can pass an arbitrary list.

Replacing the previous example with this function, you will have something like:

```
document.querySelector("div").onclick = ({target}) => {
  console.log(getIndex(target, target.parentNode.children));
}
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

actually its very simple,
if you are using jquery,,, then it is as simple as

```
$("span").click(function(){
    console.log($(this).index())
});
```

or if you are using plain javascript this should do the job

```
$("span").click(function(){
    console.log(Array.from(this.parentNode.children).indexOf(this));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution could be. While building add data attribute and when user click fetch it.

```
// Set arribute:
$("span").attr("data-id",index++);
OR
$(this).attr("data-id",index++);
// Get arribute:
$(this).attr("data-id");
```